# how to prevent stacked ordering when I do Z=X+Y? X is always on top

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's what I mean

This is my controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    if signed_in?
      @post_items = current_user.posts
      @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
      @items = @post_items + @activities
      @items.sort_by{|item| item.class == PublicActivity::Activity ? item.created_at : item.created_at}
      @items = @items.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 20)
    else
    redirect_to root_path  
    end
  end
```

As you can see in the above, this line `@items = @post_items + @activities` causes stacked ordering. All of the post_items are ordered first THAN the activities are ordered below it.

I am trying to combine BOTH into one ordering using "created_at".

How can I prevent this stacked ordering and make it order as one? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort_by` isn't doing what you think it's doing. It's returning a **new** sorted array. If you want to modify the array in-place, you have to use `sort_by!`:

```
@items.sort_by!(&:created_at)
```

Comment: how do I make it descending? It appears to be going the opposite way. I'm trying to get the newest created_at at the top

Comment: You could use `sort{|x,y| x <=> y}` ... http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort

Comment: @items.sort_by! {|item| -item.created_at}

Comment: your original answer worked, but it put the list in the opposite direction. I tried your updated answer in the comment above, but I get this error `undefined method '-@' for 2013-04-30 22:33:51 UTC:Time`

Comment: @items.sort_by! {|item| -item.created_at.to_i}